# Is there a QuickLook app that will highlight search terms within MS Word documents?

Tags: spotlight, quicklook, search

I have a client with a large number of Word documents that he needs to be able to search. He's been using Spotlight and Quick Look, which has worked pretty well.

He asked me if there was a way to have the Quick Look image automatically highlight the search terms within the Quick Look preview.

I've been googling for a Quick Look plugin, but I haven't found one?

Does anyone here know of something like this?

Answer (score 1):

This would require you to be able to pass parameters into Quicklook (the spotlight search terms) which I don't think is possible. You might be able to do this with Automator and a folder action.